# Tags: Is less more?

Tags: discussion, tags

When I'm posting a question on Stack Overflow, how many tags should I select? Is it better to use just a few key tags, or to use as many applicable tags as I can find?

For example, if I have a question about CSS3 animations, should I do all these tags:

[css-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animations)[animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animations)[css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)[css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3)[html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)

Or just simply [css-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animations) and be done?

Comment: Well, consider which tags people are likely to follow. If you only tagged `css-animations`, I would guess not too many users keep that as a favorite tag so they'll miss it. On the other hand, lots of users probably favorite `css`, meaning their homepage will be curated to include it. Don't go overboard though.

Comment: _Less_ might be _better,_ but it could never be _more_. (And yes, I know the saying; I just don't like its lack of logic) :-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There's usually sort of a happy medium for tags, where two is better than one and three is better than 5. The optimal number of tags depends on the question, of course: ideally, you want to identify all of the core topics without hitting too many tangential ones. A good start is to include the language you're working in, and then the specific library or API you're working with:

- [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) for the language
- [css-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animations) for the API

Then ask if there's anything that identifies the topic of your question *even more specifically*. For instance, [css-keyframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-keyframes) if your question is specific to that part of animation, or [google-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) if your question is in regards to a behavior specific to that browser.

In all cases, try to avoid just throwing a bunch of related tags onto the question.

Comment: So basically, three is the number thou shalt tag, and the number of the tagging shall be three. Four shalt thou not tag, neither tag thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out!

Comment: I think this is bad advice: "A good start is to include the language you're working in". In the case of Frameworks, which are likely to be the source of a big chunk of new questions, is pointless to add the language tag. Say you track the JavaScript tag and you'll see questions for Angular, Ember, Backbone, Knockout, etc. Not helpful, because probably I'll be able to answer questions for only 2, maybe 3, frameworks out of the hundreds that may exist. Also, typical framework questions are of the form "How to do X with framework Y" and not directly related to the programming language.

Comment: Depends heavily on the question, @givanse. If you *know* the language is irrelevant, then great - don't use a language tag. But often, you won't know, or you'll guess wrong - there's an old joke about asking how to add numbers using jQuery that applies here. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32446/should-jquery-questions-always-be-tagged-with-javascript

Comment: I think, to contradict the first comment, it is not  number but logic. Logically css describes the language, ccs3 describes the version, and css-animations describes the topic, tags like html would not add any value in terms of tags since...well that is kinda implied by use of CSS and animations is too broad and could reference other questions about animations in general

Comment: "Depends heavily on the question, @givanse. If you know the language is irrelevant, then great - don't use a language tag. But often, you won't know" that only apply to OP while asking the question, right? Because if I know with certain what is relevant or irrelevant to the question I can apply fitting tags.

Comment: Applies to any author/editor, @braiam. Confusion is hardly limited to askers.

Comment: @givanse and Shog9 [Relevant](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Answer (score 13):

You should select tags that make scope of the question clear for future readers and attract the right experts to the question to answer it. Experts tend to watch specific high level tags (like [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)) so always including one of those types of tags is a good idea. The more obscure the tag, the less people will be actively watching it. Any other tags help narrow down the context for someone scanning the question. For example, I watch [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) but tend to skip [sidekiq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sidekiq) because I'm not usually suited for answering Sidekiq questions.

A common rule of thumb is to ask yourself, "Would a [example-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/example-tag) expert be able to solve this problem?" If the answer is "yes," that tag is a good candidate for the question.

Use version tags if your question *only* applies to that specific version. For example, use the [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) tag if the question is *only* relevant to CSS3. If the question is also applicable to CSS2, for example, then just [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) is good enough.

General or broad tags, like [animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animations), are tricky to get right. I recommend avoiding these tags when there is a technology specific tag that can be used instead (like [css-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animations)). General tags should be used for questions that don't depend on a specific implementation.

In your specific example, I would choose to tag with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [css-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animations).

Comment: Please, no.  This is the reasoning that leads to [tag:c++] on C questions, followed by complaints when C++ answers are given.  Tags are not chosen based on what experts you want to contact; they need to accurately describe the question.

Answer (score 4):

I have found numerous people, typically novices, to max out the five tags per question, and sometimes these are very questionable associations.

There seems to be some kind of an assumption that the more tags you put, the more attention you get. Albeit true, since they often do not really read the tag description, it sometimes simply ends with the kind of attention they not intended.

IMHO one should look for the right tags. Sometimes you will use five, sometimes it will be two or three. That's all fine, as long as it makes sense.

Comment: "sometimes simply ends with the kind of attention they not intended". Yep, people sometimes get really annoyed when getting posts not reasonably relevant to the tags they filter on...

Comment: A 'tag sentence' is a very strong signal of a question what wants closure.