# Could a tag be burninated when its existance is kept up by 1 or 2 answerers?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently noticed a new MongoDB tag: [aggregation-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregation-framework)

The thing is I am unsure if this tag is right for the site, a couple of reasons:

- It has 861 questions and at least 80-90% of them are tagged with that tag by the question's answerer or another user (normally only one other user), not the asker.
- After 861 questions the tag has not caught on, a.k.a people who ask questions do not actually use it and it has no real cataloguing usefulness from what I can see.
- Normally the usage of aggregation framework is optional in questions and if it is not then the title of the question will explain the aggregation framework (partly related as well as millions more like it: [Tags: Is less more?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281094/tags-is-less-more/281095)), for example, [Mongodb aggregate not grouping documents by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474865/mongodb-aggregate-not-grouping-documents-by-date)
- aggregation-framework is an extremely broad tag, for example, SQL techs have an aggregation-framework as well, though most people just class it as part of the SQL language these days. However, to get to the bottom of it the tag could easily be used for something else and I am stunned by the fact that no one else released another program called or loosely related to "aggregation framework". If the tag were to remain I was thinking it should be at least mongodb-aggregation-framework, but that too would be useless due to it's length and complexity.

I know this is not causing any harm currently, however, I am wondering: would this tag be up for burnination considering the points above? Or would such a thing just be left alone?

Comment: None of those reasons are really good reasons for burning a tag.  Focus on the tag's ability (or inability) to "categorize the question."  See also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks, that question has been bugging my mind for a while

Comment: The tag could technically do with renaming if it is defined as the mongodb-aggregration-framework but that's about all I can see <.<

Comment: 861 questions tagged and you believe that it hasn't caught on?  That's perplexing.  You may have a point about aggregation-framework, but that's about it.  It could do with some renaming.

Comment: @Makoto 861 questions tagged by 2 users (at most, normally it is just one guy doing it all who has way too much free time on his hands), and when the main user stops doing it no one else does it,  how is that perplexing?

Comment: That argument doesn't hold water.  There are other users putting this tag in as well.  That's why I'm perplexed.

Comment: @Makoto You did check the edit history of the questions right? Out of the first page you see two askers actually tagged their questions with it, and there are even less the further you go back.

Comment: @Makoto if you actually go through you will find 80-90% of all the questions have been tagged by one guy mostly