# What is the policy for granularity on tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Lately, I've been editing questions and removing any extra or redundant tags. Before I continue doing it, I just want to make sure I'm doing the right thing.

For example, a [question about permanent storage on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615528/making-android-app-remember-data-and-saving-it-on-exit) had the tags [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save), [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), and [sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) (Android's permanent storage).

The [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag trumps [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java); [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save) has no meaning. Now, [sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) is on topic, but doesn't quite provide a classification of the question. I'd rather take it out, because I believe tags should not be as granular as covering all topics of a question; they serve just to frame it.

Comment: Link to the question in question please? Otherwise our tag experts cannot judge ;)

Comment: Are you sure there are no non-java android questions? Maybe scala or native...

Comment: At this point Android is its own set of problems. If you're dealing with data types and algorithmics, anything that can be unitested in a SE JVM, that's a java tag. If it has one call to any of the Android framework classes, it's Android tag because you're deaing with a different problem.

Comment: Similarly, if you have a tooling problem in Gradle, you're still in Android space. If you're using Kotlin or Scala or any of the non-standard languages, each has its own tag. They're enough of a rarity to deserve it.

Comment: As for C++, the few lot that use it have the android-ndk tag, plus their c++-related ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not normally a fan of editors removing tags; the more the merrier when I'm looking for a question to answer.  Clicking through from the front page to the question can easily cost me 5 minutes of my life that I'll never get back when the tags are not specific enough.

But you made the right call here, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is superfluous with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), and [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save) is useless.  They don't add an extra signal.  [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) + [sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) is perfect.  You didn't *have* to remove [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save), but removing [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) was however important, since not every Java expert knows Android.

Comment: You say _perfect_, but there is [tag:android-sharedpreferences] too. (oh, tag was created after your answer)

Answer (score 1):

> The android tag trumps java; save has no meaning. Now, sharedpreferences is on topic, but doesn't quite provide a classification of the question.

Your reasoning was spot on. A tag that doesn't connect the question with the people that are able to answer them, aren't useful at all. You can safely remove them without a second through, specially if you know what you are talking about. The languages tags are a given, the save tag [has no user other that BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/save/topusers) which consistently answer questions, and even then, he hasn't been [doing so since '13](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20[save]%20is:answer), certainly not a trend. sharedpreferences also have the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sharedpreferences/topusers), the people with most answers in them, even [Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A115145%20[sharedpreferences]%20is%3Aanswer), aren't consistently answering these questions. [Remember](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281095/792066):

> [...] ideally, you want to identify all of the core topics *without hitting too many tangential ones*. [...] In all cases, try to **avoid just throwing a bunch of related tags** onto the question.