# Burninate [getElementsByClassName]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The tag [getelementsbyclassname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementsbyclassname) is for a single javascript function which seems like a pretty specific bit of tagging compared to the usual 'language' level tags.

It has 286 questions in the last three years - I don't think this is adding anything useful. May also apply to the very similar tag [getelementbyid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementbyid) (1315 questions).

Comment: Thank you for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. For more information, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: I think if we discuss about a specific function tag, can't we just list and burn all(most) function tags? I think function tags are generally not useful, since there would be just 9,457 tags for PHP functions and methods for example and they would be so specific and not useful at all.

Comment: @Rizier123 What about a specific function like [tag:malloc]? Do you consider that useful? Where do we draw the line?

Comment: @PetahChristian Maybe a function tag is useful when you talk about that very specific implementation of it. But even then I wouldn't call it really useful.

Comment: That tag doesn't look too bad in how it is used: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206651/tag-distribution?tagname=getelementsbyclassname

Comment: The thing interesting with `getElementsByClassName` is that it returns a *live* HTML collection. I would kill `getElementById` though.

Comment: @Tunaki: I'm sorry for removing tags blindly a time ago. But is this burnination approved? Meaning that can we go one by one through the questions with "getelementsbyclassname" and close, edit, vote or in short words, take action on them including removing the tag " getelementsbyclassname"?

Comment: How about an overall `getElement(s)By` tag, and the individual functions as aliases of it? (The 's' is a bit of a problem, though)

Comment: @m69 who is searching for questions about these specific functions tho? I don't see the need.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ If consensus is reached that the tag needs to go, it would be best to post an answer documenting the progress (refer to [Shog9's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191))

Comment: ^^ Thanks, I'll follow the guidelines as per the answer you linked. But is it appropriate for a user who does not have full-edit privileges (< 2k) to carry out burnination?

Comment: @Druzion: Do not start editing! Didn't you see [Tunaki's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320569/burninate-getelementsbyclassname?noredirect=1#comment331000_320569). Till there is an official answer which says to burninate it, and it also gets highly upvoted, do not do it. It has still not been decided whether to burninate it or not. You'll fall into a big hole. I had once just blindly started and finished burnination on a tag, even before it had been decided. The question had 27 upvotes. I thought the same thing as you thought, but then fell very badly.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ Okay, I won't. But what do you mean by *official answer*, by a mod?

Comment: @Druzion: It matters. In many cases, it is a mod. But even an answer by a normal user, saying that it has to be burninated, and it also reaches about +20. This is very rare, and the safest steps to follow is an answer by a mod. But many times when a mod doesn't respond, a normal user can post an answer, saying the tag to be burninated. if the process has already started you can burninate. But this time, it hasn't even been decided if we have to burninate. It looks like we are going to, but till then, do not do anything. I had done the same mistake (can see me apologizing in first comment ).

Comment: Funny fact: [**No user consistently answers or ask questions with this tag**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/getelementsbyclassname/topusers)

Comment: @Braiam based on your data I see users there with 9 answers for this specific tag, and users with 3 questions on that tag. I don't know if I should make any conclusions based on that, but seems some users frequent it.

Comment: For the requet itself, I think we should burninate tags that are for some reason harmful, misleading or something like that. I'm not fully convinced on what's the problem with this one.

Comment: @eis none of them have answered questions with this tag but without javascript. I would say that they effectively answered JS question, irrespectively they were also tagged [getelementsbyclassname] or not.

Comment: @Braiam well, pretty much every technology in the java ecosystem is also tagged with java as well, for example. There aren't very many questions tagged with swing that aren't tagged with java: that's a common way things work in SO. I still claim that saying "no user consistently answers or asks questions with this tag" seems to be factually incorrect.

Comment: Covering Shog's fourth point in his answer, this tag seems to always be used in the same DOM context, most often with JavaScript, sometimes with VBA or VB.NET. As such it doesn't look like there is any ambiguity over its use.

Comment: @eis well, unlike "swing", the tag is just a function, what you say is equivalent to gtk or Qt. They are by orders of magnitude more complex, with several underlying functions (see what I did there?) in which people can specialize.

Comment: @Kyll did you read my answer? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320723/792066 Are you sure?

Answer (score 24):

> a pretty specific bit of tagging compared to the usual 'language' level tags

That's not a reason to burninate anything. Given how often it is used, it's definitely not *too* specific.

I'd say **No, don't burninate**. The tag doesn't meet [the official criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

- *Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?* - Yes.
- *Is it unambiguous?* - Yes.
- *Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?* - Yes.
- *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?* - Yes.
- *Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?* - Yes, I say. You seem to disagree. Now what?

The tag does not do any harm. So the simple default is to keep it.

Comment: `The tag doesn't meet the official criteria:` It seems you are proving that the tag is indeed meeting the official criteria.

Comment: @Marc-Andre: Doesn't meet any of the criteria for being deleted, I meant.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm not always looking at burnination request I guess I was missing some context.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that even if it doesn't "follow" Shog's guideline, this tag is doing more harm than good... actually, there's no good, just harm (no ham, ham is good).

"Why?" getElementsByClassName is commonly known as a Javascript function (I would say almost exclusive). The other programming context you can find it is VBA/VBScript. Those big two, right? Well, what about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23237565/792066)? Badly tagged, right? [This other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30815459/792066)? [And this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29482867/792066)? [How about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16522795/792066)?

Frankly, this tag *is being misused* and is **causing harm**. This tag is displacing more relevant tags, like javascript, and in some cases it doesn't make even sense, like the selenium/python question. This tag needs a manual and very annoying retag/cleanup, which could have been avoided if we didn't create this tag in the first place.

The above may not be enough reason, how about setting a very bad precedent? Tags has always been considered as *flat*. That means that there isn't any vertical relationship between them, that I apply tag X doesn't imply that tag Y should be used. In this case, this tag alone may *imply* that JavaScript should be used (as described on the tag excerpt, but as we remember is also available on VBA/Script), but this is not recognized by the system.

Those users asking those questions doesn't have the best exposure that a language tag gives them, because they think that applying this tag is implied that other more popular tags are also counted. The reduced exposure results on having a reduced pool of users that can answer their questions, which in most cases aren't experts, reducing the overall quality of SO. Basically, with this tag we are partially implementing a [tiered SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252781/792066) which has always been considered as a "bad experience for all involved".

Comment: It's a DOM function, of which there are many implementations in and for many languages. There are published standards for its implementation and behavior that function largely independently of client language even. So it shouldn't surprise you that folks ask questions related to its use on multiple platforms. Your examples could benefit from *more* tags, but hardly suffer from these; arguably the expertise is more likely to be found in someone familiar with the API than with the language (but not the API).

Comment: @Shog9 well, I still call foul on these two http://stackoverflow.com/q/30815459/792066 http://stackoverflow.com/q/23237565/792066 BTW, my examples would actually benefit useful tags, not just [looking for a magic number](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281095/792066),