# Should we burninate tags referencing methods?

Tags: discussion, tags

I use to move around the javascript tag, and I found the [getelementbyid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementbyid) tag. I think that we can't have a tag for every method in every language. In the tag description it says.

> getElementByID is an essential method commonly used in JavaScript in
>   the browser to retrieve a particular element node in a HTML or XML
>   document by its ID.

How is determined that is an *essential* method? I know is a common method but it is just too broad. Other tags referencing methods:

- [getelementsbytagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementsbytagname)
- [getelementsbyname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementsbyname)
- [getelementsbyclassname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementsbyclassname)
- [queryselectall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryselectall) (*)

(*) *this has just 6 question, and the method is `querySelectorAll` if it's referencing the javascript method*

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320569/792066

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I asked about tags referencing methods, not about a specific tag like the question you are pointing.

Answer (score 1):

Why? What harm are they doing?

Folks ask plenty of questions about them, they certainly don't suffer from being *ambiguous*... If they're not *actively causing harm* then don't worry about them.

See also: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

Comment: They do cause harm http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320723/792066

Comment: Nope. Finding poorly-asked questions in a tag isn't evidence that the tag is bad unless you can demonstrate that the topic represented by the tag is *itself* inappropriate for the site (or the tag is misleading enough to suggest a different topic to new users).

Comment: Sometimes I get the idea that y'all would be happier with a one tag per question limit and a set of maybe a dozen tags so broad they covered everything possible on the site. "Look! Nothing can possibly be mistagged because tags are now meaningless!"

Comment: Well, users not having the best possible answer because a poor selection of tags is *worse*, ah, and in that case, tags are effectively meaningless.

Comment: Yeah... Compare the "unanswered rate" between questions in more specific tags vs. tags like [tag:javascript] or [tag:c#] and tell me you're making a good bet forgoing specificity, @Braiam. Yes, you reach a much larger audience... But so do thousands of other people every day. If your question sucks, you're gonna have issues no matter what. Ideally, you use *all* applicable tags to get both breadth and specificity... And savvy askers know this.